# Translating a query to use Zend_Db_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

I'm having some problems translating this query to use ZF's `Zend_Db_Select`:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.description 
FROM memberships AS m
JOIN blogs AS b ON b.id = m.blog_id 
WHERE m.user_id = ? 
ORDER BY m.created
LIMIT 0, 30
```

(this query works and returns results)

`Memberships` is a link table between `blogs` and `users`. It's a simple `| id | blog_id | user_id |` affair.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// $table = Zend_Db_Table instance, $id = a user id
$select = $table->select()
->from(array('m' => 'memberships'), array('b.id', 'b.title', 'b.description'))
->join(array('b' => 'blogs'), 'b.id = m.blog_id')
->where('m.user_id = ?', (int) $id)
->order('m.created DESC')
->limit(0, 30);
```

This is the (strange (to me)) error I'm getting:

> `#0: Select query cannot join with another table`
>
> Occurred on line 211 of `D:\...\library\Zend\Db\Table\Select.php`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When retrieved from your table object, the statement will be limited to that table I think. The `Zend_Db_Table::select()` methods returns a `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object which is a subclass of `Zend_Db_Select` and imposes this restriction. Try this instead:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($adapter);
$select->from( 'my_table_name' )->join( ...
```

If you prefer, the following should be equivalent:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );
$db->select()->from( 'my_table_name' )->join( ...
```

Comment: This worked as I wanted it to. However it seems to return the results as an array, rather than as an object? Not a problem, just wondering why.

Comment: It shouldn't, actually. How do you execute the select statement? $select->query() should return either a PDO_Statement or a Zend_Db_Statement.

Answer (score 15):

You could also still use the traditional $model->select() object by adding setIntegrityCheck(false), like so.

```
$select = $table->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('m' => 'memberships'), array('b.id', 'b.title', 'b.description'))
->join(array('b' => 'blogs'), 'b.id = m.blog_id')
->where('m.user_id = ?', (int) $id)
->order('m.created DESC')
->limit(0, 30);
```

This disables the check that is throwing the exception:

```
#0: Select query cannot join with another table
```