# Error while joining tables with Zend_Db

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Why am I getting this:

```
An error occurred

Application error

Exception information:

Message: Select query cannot join with another table
```

while trying to join two tables?

I have this line code inside my model which extends **Zend_Db_Table_Abstract**

```
public function getProjects() {
    $select = $this->select()
            ->from(array('sub' => $this))
            ->join(array('main' => 'main_projects'), 'main.mai_id = sub.mai_id');
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

And I use this in my controller: `$this->view->entries = $this->sub_projects->getProjects();`

Why the hell I get this error? I just want to make a simple join

```
SELECT sub.*, main.mai_title FROM sub_projects AS sub INNER JOIN main_projects AS main ON sub.mai_id = projects.mai_id;
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is your solution and explanation : http://www.mail-archive.com/fw-general@lists.zend.com/msg24553.html
Another solution here : [Translating a query to use Zend_Db_Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520131/translating-a-query-to-use-zend-db-select)

Comment: then I get: ` SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ccgss.object' doesn't exist`

Comment: Actually I also had to change `$this`for the name of the table

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.